# Split a sentence into two words and store as key, value in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, split

I need to split a sentence into two strings, the first string store as key and the second string store as value in HashMap.
For example:

```
String sent="4562=This is example";
```

This is my sentence, I split into two strings using the following line:

```
sent.split("=");
```

I want to store the first string (`4562`) as key, and the second string store as value in HashMap.

Can you please share your ideas or solution for problem?

Comment: did you try hashmap.put(key,value) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stating your own answer:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); //initialize the hashmap
String s = "4562=This is example"; //initialize your string
String[] parts = s.split("="); //split it on the =
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]); //put it in the map as key, value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store in a hashmap like this:

```
String sent = "4562=This is example";
String[] split = sent.split("=");
HashMap<Integer, String> keysValues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
keysValues.put(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), split[1]);
```

You can store Integer as key and String as value...or String, String either way will work depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the method split returns a String Array so store the result into an String array and call the hashmap.put(key,value) method

like this

```
String[] a = split.("=");
hasmap.put(a[0],a[1]);
```

note if you have several = in the string you will loose some of it in the value of the hashmap!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String s = "4562=This is example";
        String[] parts = s.split("=");
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            myMap.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }

        System.out.println(myMap);
    }
```

**Output**

{4562=This is example}

```
enter code here
```